# how to configure logging on using USB token windows server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, usb, token

I have a USB token, and I want clients to use their token to log on to domain, I followed the steps from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378897(v=ws.10).aspx)

a brief definition of what I have done yet:

after installing domain and CA-server, I defined a special group, created a special certificate template (smart card log on), mapped them.

now the client successfully receives the certificate and I successfully installed the certificate with its special software on the USB token, finally the USB token is ready!

I defined some policies within the server to enable the smart-card logon, but there isn't any change on logon page!

what's wrong with it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although I had used the USB stick before in the same windows for installing certificate on it, some time after, I accidentally found out that there is a driver for it. I installed it and windows recognized it as a smart card! done!

so it means that reading the USB token is not equal to using it as a smart-card.